# SQL custom priority

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to order table by multiple rows, one of them is "custom". I have 4 values in that column, and priority should be -60 or 151, and then 30 or 111. So I have just that specific 4 values, and if like -60 is after 151, it shouldn't be sorted, and if -60 is after 30, it should be sorted.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't go wrong with 42! Seriously, please provide more details and give an example. Do you expect us to understand this question?

Comment: Mikael understood, and that was it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a case statement in the order by.

```
select SomeColumn
from YourTable
order by case custom 
           when -60 then 1
           when 151 then 1
           when 30 then 2
           when 111 then 2
         end
```

Or something like this

```
select SomeColumn
from YourTable
order by nullif(nullif(custom, -60), 151)
```

Comment: @elninho: No-one seems to have told you that you can (and are greatly encouraged to) [formally accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?") the answer that has worked for you. That is a nice way to thank the person who helped you, as well as a way of helping others to find the right answer more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use query like that:

```
select *
from Table1
order by
    field1,
    field2,
    field3,           
    case
       when custom = -60 then 0
       when custom = 151 then 0
       when custom = 30 then 1
       when custom = 111 then 1
    end asc
```